# How do I use a class wstringstream variable?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have a `std::wstringstream` that I'm using as sort of a buffer in my class and it is used by a good portion of the methods in this class. However, when I try to do something like this:

```
#include <sstream>

class foo
{
  public:
    void methodA(int x, int y); // Uses mBufferStream
    void methodB(int x, int y); // Uses mBufferStream

  private:
    std::wstringstream mBufferStream;
};
```

I get the following error:

> error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'

This isn't my exact class obviously, but it is the same setup. Any thoughts as to what I may be doing wrong? I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2005.

[Edit] showing use in method body in .cpp file (as an example of it's use):

```
void foo::methodA(int x, int y)
{
  mBufferStream << "From " << x << " To " << y;
  externalfunction(mBufferStream.str());  // Prints to message service
  mBufferStream.str(L"");
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles fine on g++ 4.2 - does this exact code fail to compile on your compiler? It looks fine.

Comment: Any example of how your using mBufferStream in body?

Comment: which of those three lines causes the error?

Comment: Hrm,  When I put the wstringstream in the class containing the message logging, the error goes away.  I wonder what would cause this error to occur...

Comment: We need to see the real code to give you real answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the compiler is implicitly declaring a copy constructor for class `foo`. `std::wstringstream` is noncopyable, because it inherits from `ios_base`.

Change your class to this:

```
#include <sstream>

class foo
{
  public:
    void methodA(int x, int y); // Uses mBufferStream
    void methodB(int x, int y); // Uses mBufferStream

  private:
    std::wstringstream mBufferStream;
    foo(const foo&); //noncopyable
    void operator=(const foo&)
};
```

and the compiler should point you at the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the missing `;` on the `externalfunction` line is a typo, I wasn't able to get your exact error message, but it looks like perhaps `externalfunction` expects a `std::string` as its parameter. In fact `mBufferStream.str()` provides a `std::wstring` which can't be implicitly converted.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, thanks for the catch.  The external function is overloaded to take wstring and const wstrings.  I only get the error when I have the wstring in the header.  If I put it in the method, it works fine.